# Conditional directives based on User-Agent with Apache 2.2.x?

Tags: apache-2.2, configuration, httpd.conf, encoding, conditional

I want to implement something like the following in our Apache httpd configuration:

```
    <If "%{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !~ /something/">
        RemoveEncoding .gz .tgz
        AddType application/x-gzip .gz
    </If>
```

but my understanding is that this conditional `<If>` syntax only works with Apache 2.4.x. Unfortunately, I'm stuck with Apache 2.2.x for the time being. Is there a way to do this with Apache 2.2.x? Perhaps using `BrowserMatch` and an environment variable? Thanks!